# How to run the Go executable file generated after building the Go file?

Tags: go

After I build the main.go file using `go build go.main`, I get the main executable file. How do I run the main file? If I do `go run main.go`, it automatically builds + runs the executable. But I want to know the command to run the already build executable file.

Comment: The same way you'd run any other executable. `./program` or `program.exe`.

Comment: After you run `go build main.go`, there will be a new file with the name of the  folder containing your `main.go` file. That is the executable. If the directory containing the `main.go` file is named `toto`, on unix you have to type `./toto` to execute it. On windows. the executable will have a `.exe` extension. You should be able to execute it by typing `toto.exe` according to @tkausl comment. I’m a unix user. So I don’t know how to do this on Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running an executable is an operation handled by the operating system, not by go itself. In fact, it's the whole point of having executables in the first place.

As tkausl said, you run it as you would run any other executable. For exemple, on Linux or Mac OS, you would use `./main`. On Windows, from the command line you can run `main.exe`. You can also simply double click it.